# How to Check if evim.vim loaded instead of default.vim to change Window title

Tags: vimrc, gvim, evim

Hello I intend to change title of vim/gvim window only if vim -y/easy is started. I know that evim.vim is loaded, but If I change the titl using evim.vim , and I upgrade the vim, I will lost my change. is there anyway to check if vim loadded via evim or default.vim

Thank you

I know how to change the title, I only need to check if it's on evim or default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, you have to capture the output of `:scriptnames` and parse it to see if `evim.vim` is there. But for all practical purposes it must be sufficient to check if `:h 'insertmode'` is on.

```
if &insertmode
    " this is evim
else
    " normal vim
endif
```

Also worth mentioning that `$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim` simply checks `if v:progname =~? "evim"`. However, this only covers the case of `evim` symlink, not `vim -y` on the command-line. If really needed you can also take `:h v:argv` and see if the latter is the case, but I don't think it's worth it.

Comment: Thank you, this achieve what I need. Thanks